# Ошибка c3867. Как исправить? Не могу понять куда вставлять '&'

Tags: c++

Выдает ошибку:

> "error C3867: "Game::chapter_one": нестандартный синтаксис; используйте "&", чтобы создать указатель на член".

Полазил по интернету, но мало чего понятного нашел... Как исправить ее?

Файл Source.cpp:

```
#include "gameteh.h"


using namespace std;

int main(void) {
    Game *game = new Game;
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    game->chapter_one;


    cin.get();
    delete game;
    return 0;
}
```

файл gameteh.h:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include<locale.h>
#include<windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;
class Game {
private:
std::string player(string player_name) {
    cout << "Введите имя" << endl;
    cin >> player_name;
    return 0;
}


private: 
std::string lose_round = "Вы проиграли бой.";
std::string win_round = "Вы победили!";
std::string repeat = "Введите номер дейсвтия";
int index_rounds = 0;
std::string string_rounds = "Завершено раундов - " + index_rounds;

public:
void chapter_one(int choise) {

    cout << "Тёмный лес вокруг наступил,\n";
    cout << "Вдруг из земли вылезло чудище,\n";
    cout << "Это был слизняк.\n";
    cout << "Что вы будете делать?\n";
    cout << "1. Бросаться солью. \n";
    cout << "2. Махать мечем. \n";
    cout << "3. Бежать. \n";
    cin >> choise;
    switch (choise)
    {
    case 1: win_round; break;
    case 2: lose_round; index_rounds++; string_rounds;  break;
    case 3: lose_round; index_rounds++; string_rounds; break;
    default: repeat; break;
    }
}
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

изменить

```
Game *game = new Game;
```

на

```
 Game *game = new Game();
```

и

```
 game->chapter_one;
```

на

```
 game->chapter_one(Параметр );
```

Проблему с параметром исправить можно так:

```
...
public:
void chapter_one() {
    int choise = 0;
    ...
}
...
```

или если я не забыл с++ так:

```
int main(void) {
    Game *game = new Game();

    int  choise = 0;
    game->chapter_one(choise);
}
    ...
    void chapter_one(int & choise) {...}
```

Comment: error C2660: Game::chapter_one: функция не принимает 0 аргументов
Теперь пишет эту запись.

Comment: я уже исправил в ответе, нужен параметр

Comment: Извиняюсь за глупость, но что именно вставлять? int choise - ругается, choise - тоже.

Comment: У тебя не правильная логика в программе, сейчас в ответе напишу варианты

Comment: Спасибо, 2 вариант помог.